# Address ordering in static, stack and heap memory allocation?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-address

I am trying to write a program that shows that addresses of consecutive variables allocated either on static, stack or heap memory.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

void stack_f() {
    // array on stack
    char stack_arr[3] = {'a', 'b', 'c'};

    // stack memory addresses
    std::cout <<"\nStack memory addresses.\n";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 3; ++i) std::cout <<"&stack_arr["<< i <<"] "
                                   << reinterpret_cast<void*>(&stack_arr[i]) <<'\n';
}

//================================================================================
int main () {
    // array on static storage
    static char global_arr[3] = {'a', 'b', 'c'};

    // array on heap
    char *heap_arr = new char[3];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 3; ++i) heap_arr[i] = 'a' + i;

    // Print addresses of the three arrays 

    // static memory addresses
    std::cout <<"Static memory addresses.\n";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 3; ++i) std::cout <<"&global_arr["<< i <<"] "
                                   << reinterpret_cast<void*>(&global_arr[i]) <<'\n';
    // stack memory addresses
    stack_f();

    // heap memory addresses
    std::cout <<"\nHeap memory addresses.\n";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 3; ++i) std::cout <<"&heap_arr["<< i <<"] "
                                   << reinterpret_cast<void*>(&heap_arr[i]) <<'\n';
    delete [] heap_arr;
    getchar();
}
```

The result I get is:

[image]

Which is not what I expect<sup>1</sup>, as addresses on the stack should grow from large to small.

What I've misunderstood here?

---

<sup>1. I'm expecting the addresses of variables located on the static and heap memory to grow from small to large hex numbers, while the addresses of the stack to grow in reverse order.</sup>

<sup>64-bit Windows 7, Microsoft Visual C++ 2010</sup>

Comment: `&stack_arr[0]` is equivalent to `stack_arr + 0`, `&stack_arr[1]` to `stack_arr + 1`; i.e. increasing addresses. (You can't have arrays that are indexed "backwards" if they're on the stack and "forwards" if they're allocated somewhere else – all code that accesses a pointer would need to have two special cases.) If you create two arrays and compare the arrays' addresses you will see that they are as you expect.

Comment: Which compiler? Which platform? What version of both? None of this has much to do with C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you've misunderstood is simply that while the stack grows downward on x86, x86-64, and many other modern processors, arrays are allocated as single blocks, and hence increasing indices increase addresses. Once that is borne in mind your results are what one would expect.

Comment: Each array could be seen as separate element, right? So, if I call the function (or different function containing another array) twice the addresses of the second call should be smaller?

Comment: That would disrupt pointer arithmetic. Pointer to heap behaving differently than pointer to stack? We don't want that either, thanks.

Comment: @simplicis No, since the stack is freed on exit. If you call it twice, you probably will see the same addresses.

Comment: @Sami Kuhmonen Exactly what you say :)

Comment: @Sami Kuhmonen When two arrays are defined and their addresses printed in  function `stack_f()`, the expected behaviour is shown.

Comment: @simplicisveritatis:  If you have two calls to `stack_f` *at the same time* (the function calls itself), then yes you would get different addresses.  If you call it, return, and then call it again, you will get the same addresses.

Comment: @Martin Bonner i.e. in a recursive call, rather than consecutive, right?

Comment: Also, beware:  None of this behaviour is guaranteed by the language.  A new compiler might do things completely differently (but it is interesting to understand how your particular compiler is implementing things).

Comment: If you had the same function create two separate locals then it would **likely** go downward, but there's no reason why the order of allocation need match the order in the function compiled.

Comment: @simplicisveritatis : Recursive - exactly.